# Copy/move or allocate dynamically c functions

Tags: function, pointers, copy, move, allocation

How can I copy, move or allocate function data in c?
Help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

for example I have:

```
int  func(int x, int y)
  {
    //instructions
  }

int (*copyOfFunc)(int x, int y);
```

At a certain point I want to store func in copyOfFunc. 
I already know how to give copyOfFunc the address of func, but what if I want to copy func in an other address?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "function data". Can you elaborate? There is a memcpy() function which is used to copy storage in general.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. I don't know the term "function data". In C there is only 3 types of data that I know of: global, stack and heap.

Answer (score 0):

what do you exactly mean by

> but what if I want to copy func in an other address?

?

you want to let another pointer point to you function ? or do you want function pointer stored in specific adress ?

hope this code sample helps you

```
#include<stdio.h>

int func(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

void do_please(int a, int b, int (*some_func) (int, int)) 
{
    printf("%d, %d ? %d\n", a, b, some_func(a, b));
}


int main () 
{
    printf("1, 2 ? %d\n", func(1, 2));

    int (*my_func) (int, int)  = func;

    do_please(3, 4, my_func);

    int (*other_func) (int, int)  = my_func;

    do_please(5, 6, other_func);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I want to store the func information into another location, almost like when you have a char* and copy/move its contents with memcpy/memmove

Comment: i dotn know if there is any access to this information. Basicly you a have a pointer to function, assuming this is the adress where its code start, you need to know its size and then use malloc + memcopy. Looke at this [post](http://www.motherboardpoint.com/getting-code-size-function-c-t95049.html) maybe it can help you further